# Is there a good shortcut for modifying python variables using methods?

Tags: python, string, methods, replace

`i += 1` can be used instead of `i = i + 1`.

Is there a similar shorthand for `string = string.replace(...)`?

Comment: Strings are immutable, so no, there is no similar shorthand if you are thinking of strings, and so it seems judging from the tags you used... On the contrary, mutable objects have methods that modify the object in place and return `None`,  canonical (and erroneous) example `[3,7,2,9,1].sort()`

Comment: @gboffi he's saying is there a (say) `x r= ...` syntax instead of `x = x.replace(...)`. Like `x += 'something'`. Not to do with mutability (as the `+=` syntax works with strings), just to do with whether or not you can do that with replace as well as assignment.

Comment: `i += 1` isn't just syntactic sugar for `i = i + 1`  ; it invokes a different method (`i.__iadd__` instead of `i.__add__`). There is no general syntax for `a = a.method()`.

Comment: @RobertGrant yes, that's what I meant. It felt like a waste of time/space to have to type the same variable name twice for such a simple operation, and I was wondering if there was a more "pythonic" way of doing it. Can someone explain why my question has been downvoted? I don't understand.

Comment: @byntje no idea, but if you're happy with one of the answers below, please accept :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, because there is no built-in syntax for this.

For a string, you can still use `+=`:

```
>>> x = "hello"
>>> x += " world"
>>> x
'hello world'
```

Because += is defined for strings. There just isn't an assignment operator for replace.

Comment: A downvote without a comment. Come on, downvoter. You're better than this.

Answer (score 0):

The type string supports the += operator. You can write `str += "hello"` but such shortening does not work for functions. The type string is immutable

A function like `string.replace` returns a new string and therefore you have to replace it against your old string (if that's what you want).